# Ошибка Unable to resolve service for type 'EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

появилась ошибка:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator [PlayVersus.Models.User]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`

при добавлении в существующий Web Api Identity.

Startup.cs:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextFactory<DataBaseContext>(opt => opt.UseNpgsql(DataBaseContext.GetConnectionSting()));
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(IDbRepository<>), typeof(DbRepository<>));
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(options =>
        {
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        }).AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataBaseContext>();
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(
            opt =>
            {
                opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = AuthToken.ISSUER,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = AuthToken.AUDIENCE,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = AuthToken.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            }
        );
    }
```

DataBaseContext:

public class DataBaseContext :IdentityDbContext, IDisposable
{

```
    public override DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityRole> IdentityRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Discipline> Disciplines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }

    public DataBaseContext(DbContextOptions<DataBaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        
    }     
    public static string GetConnectionSting()
    {
        return new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Host = "localhost",
            Port = 5432,
            Database = "xxxxxxxx",
            Username = "xxxxxx",
            Password = "******",
            Timeout = 300
        }.ConnectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User").HasKey(c=>c.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Platform>().ToTable("Platforms");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Discipline>().HasKey(c => c.TournamentID);
    }
}
```

Возможна ли проблема, что я использую Postgres?

P.S. Перепробовал кучу советов и на github и на Stackoverflov(en/ru)?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что я использовал AddDbContextFactory и AddIdentityCore одновременно при этом не совпадал жизненный цикл у AddDbContextFactory - Singleton, AddIdentityCore - Scoped. Добавив строку:

```
   services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(p => p.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>>().CreateDbContext());
```

Исходный ответ тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618830/identity-stores-with-db-context-factory